# Remove Wordpress User Meta Boxes?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a built in function that allows one to remove all the Meta Boxes from a user profile when singing up/ editing?

I'd like to have username, email and password only. None of the other junk.

Comment: Please mark an answer and/or add your progress/solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an easy way either, but since the other fields are all optional you could use css-settings to hide all fields you don't need/want.

Certainly not the best way but it would achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: The [`user-edit.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/user-edit.php) page outputs everything without letting you come between it, so indeed, hiding them via CSS is the way to go, unless you want to capture the output with output buffering and filter it server-side, but that will be very clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the delete_user_meta() function.

Comment: This function is to delete certain data from the user-entry in the database, not for removing form-fields from the profile page.

Comment: I understand your meaning now. :P
Not easy.